# Creating and testing a Fraction class

Tags: c#, homework, rational-numbers

The exercise is as follows:

> Create a class called Fraction that can be used to represent the ratio of two integers.
>   Include appropriate constructors, properties, and methods. If the denominator becomes
>   zero, throw and handle an exception. Create an application class to test the Fraction class.

The program runs.  Will someone look over my code for this exercise?

Fraction.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Part2
{
    public class Fraction
    {
        private int numerator;
        private int denominator;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize the fraction properties
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="numerator">Upper number</param>
        /// <param name="denominator">Lower number</param>
        public Fraction(int numerator, int denominator)
        {
            this.Numerator = numerator;
            this.Denominator = denominator;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Access tot he numerator property
        /// </summary>
        public int Numerator
        {
            get { return this.numerator; }
            set { this.numerator = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Access to the denominator property
        /// </summary>
        public int Denominator
        {
            get { return this.denominator; }
            set
            {
                if (value == 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception("0 denominator");
                }

                this.denominator = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Return a string representation of a fraction
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Displayable attribute</returns>
        public override string ToString()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(this.Numerator + "/" + this.numerator);
            sb.Append(" or ");
            sb.Append(this.Numerator / this.Denominator);

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Application.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Part2
{
    public class Application
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Entry point of the program
        /// </summary>
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create a fraction
            Fraction f1 = new Fraction(1, 2);
            Console.WriteLine(f1);

            try
            {
                // Create another fraction
                Fraction f2 = new Fraction(2, 0);
                Console.WriteLine(f2);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would he allow unit testing to be considered a class to "test" your class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your class is pretty much useless. If you have a class that represents a fraction, you should be able to do operations with it that you can do with a fraction, like addition, subtraction, multiplication and division (possibly using operator overloading). Another possible operation is fraction simplification.

Also, you shouldn't throw `Exception`, you should instead a custom type that inherits from `Exception` (called something like `ZeroDenominatorException`) and throw that.

And your `Main()` isn't very realistic. In real code, you wouldn't write code that you know will always throw an exception. So I think that your `try` should be around both of your `new Fraction()` statements.

Also, if you're going to have all the operations I have mentioned above, a better application to show that would be a very simple fraction calculator.

Something like:

```
Enter numerator:
1
Enter denominator:
4
Enter operation:
+
Enter numerator:
3
Enter denominator:
4
Result: 4/4
Simplifies result: 1/1
```

Comment: Thank you. I will change some of the things you mentioned. I will refrain from adding anything that the exercise doesn't explicitly call for like math operations(although it would be a better program). Less to grade = less chance for grade deduction. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: [you should actually throw an `IllegalArgumentException`.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657887/how-should-i-throw-a-divide-by-zero-exception-in-java-without-actually-dividing)

Comment: @JakobWeisblat This is not Java. In .Net you could use `ArgumentException` or `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: @svick oops. I should look at tags more carefully.

Comment: Could also use `DivideByZeroException`